# The jpeg images I am saving from my android application are not fully clear

Tags: android, image, bitmap, jpeg

I have to save android.media.Image as bitmaps and eventually compress into jpeg.The images saved are half image and half grey.Also the images are rotated.

#### #

image = frame.acquireCameraImage();

```
                    Log.i("Bitmap", "-60");
                    Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                    Log.i("Bitmap", "-6");
                    ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
                    ByteBuffer buffer1 = planes[1].getBuffer();
                    Log.i("Bitmap", "-15");
                    ByteBuffer buffer2 = planes[2].getBuffer();
                    Log.i("Bitmap", "-7");
                    int format = image.getFormat();
                    int width = image.getWidth();
                    int height = image.getHeight();
                    Log.i("Bitmap", "-20");
                    Rect cropRect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
                    Log.i("Bitmap", "-8");
                    byte[] arr = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                    buffer.get(arr);
                    Log.i("Bitmap", "-9");
                    byte[] arr1 = new byte[buffer1.remaining()];
                    buffer1.get(arr1);
                    Log.i("Bitmap", "-10");
                    byte[] arr2 = new byte[buffer2.remaining()];
                    buffer2.get(arr2);
                    image.close();
                    Log.i("Bitmap", "-5");
                    byte[] c = new byte[arr.length + arr1.length + arr2.length];
                    Log.i("Bitmap", "-1");
                    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, c, 0, arr.length);
                    Log.i("Bitmap", "-2");
                    System.arraycopy(arr1, 0, c, arr.length, arr1.length);
                    Log.i("Bitmap", "-3");
                    System.arraycopy(arr2, 0, c, arr1.length, arr2.length);
                    Log.i("Bitmap", "0");
                    YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(c,ImageFormat.NV21,width,height, null);
                    Log.i("Bitmap", "1");
                    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    Log.i("Bitmap", "1");
                    yuvImage.compressToJpeg(cropRect, 90, b);
                    byte[] jpegData = b.toByteArray();
                    Log.i("Bitmap", "2");
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inPreferQualityOverSpeed=true;
                    // int scaleFactor;
                    //options.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
                    Log.i("Bitmap", "3");
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegData, 0, jpegData.length, options);
                    saveBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Removing the log statements and adding proper spacing would make the code a lot easier to read for others. But at least the third arraycopy has a wrong offset

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegData, 0, jpegData.length, options);

this is your code please change it like

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegData, 100, jpegData.length, options);

in your code you were setting the quality as 0 hence the issue, please change it to 100 to have the image as it is.
 Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but that results i this:10649/com.google.ar.core.examples.java.helloar E/HelloArActivity: Exception on the OpenGL thread
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:626)